# Can bundle-image EC2-AMI-Tools commnd convert any type of image into AMI image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to upload my images to Amazon S3 so can Bundle-image command bundle any type of image like qcow2,VDI,VMDk and convert it to AMI

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this using the command line tools.

Check this out

http://flurdy.com/docs/ec2/ami/

Comment: Actually i want to import my virtual box image to my Amazon EC2 .so can i import VDI format image to Amaozn same can i import VDI,VMDK,qcow2 images?